# Image Component in nextjs with CSS styles for mobiles

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

I am using Image Nextjs Component to put my image in the center of the page [i want the picture to be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLdAv.png) and remain its reel size but it has been pixelized. plusm when i reduce the the screen width the picture doesn't appear correctly for the small screen views [a part of the picture disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KutB.png)

```
<div
   style={{
     position: 'relative',
     width: '1000px',
     height: '500px',
     alignItems: 'center',
   }}
>         
 <Image src='/services.png' alt='' layout='fill' objectFitt='fill' />
</div>
```

I think the problem is from the div style. I tried so hard to fix the width and height of the div but i still get the deformed picture in the page. Also i changed the objectFitt to 'cover' but same problem :(
I appreciate any help and any explanation of how to put an image without being pixelized.
Thank you so much.
The picture size is: width=1454px and height=455px
[here is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9cKo.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should change the div's width from 1000px to 100% to make it responsive and choose height according to different screen sizes. try out this-

```js
                 <div
                    style={{
                        position: 'relative',
                        width: '100%',
                        height: '300px',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                    }}
                >
                    <Image src={main_image} alt='' layout='fill' objectFitt='fill' />
                </div>
```